# How to remove margins in print in react-js?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, web, printing

[image]

I am trying to print the barcode labels IN REACT JS ... but the issue is when i try to print it adds margin to left and right automatically and width is not working at all.

I tried making pdf of barcode but that too not worked either.

I tried adding css and tried lot of things but it did not get fixed.

**REACT CODE**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button, Col, Container, Navbar, Row } from 'reactstrap';
import JsBarcode from 'jsbarcode';

const PrintBarcodeCreate = () => {
  const products = [
    { no: '546493176226', name: 'Mugdal 500gm', mrp: 1000, salePrice: 990, expDate: "10/10/2023" },
    { no: '546493176226', name: 'Mugdal 500gm', mrp: 1000, salePrice: 990, expDate: "10/10/2023" },
    { no: '546493176226', name: 'Mugdal 500gm', mrp: 1000, salePrice: 990, expDate: "10/10/2023" },
    { no: '546493176226', name: 'Mugdal 500gm', mrp: 1000, salePrice: 990, expDate: "10/10/2023" },

  ];


  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = "POS Create - Ajspire Technologies";

    // Generate barcodes using JsBarcode
    products.forEach(data => {
      JsBarcode(`#barcode-${data.no}`, data.no, {
        format: "CODE128",
        displayValue: true,
        fontSize: 10,
        width: 1.2,
        height: 25,
        margin: 0,
      });
    });
  }, []);

  const handlePrint = () => {
    const printWindow = window.open('', '_blank');
    printWindow.document.write(document.getElementById('printable-area').innerHTML);
    printWindow.document.close();
    printWindow.print();
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="page-content" id='hide_scroll' >
        <Button color="primary" onClick={handlePrint}>Print Barcodes</Button>
        <Container>
          <div id="printable-area" style={{ pageBreakAfter: "always", height: "25mm" }}>
            {products.map((data, index) => (
              index % 2 === 0 && (
                <div style={{ display: "flex", }} key={index + 1}>
                  <div style={{ flex: 1, width: "38mm", height: "25mm", marginTop: index === 0 ? "0px" : "10px", border: "2px solid red", textAlign: "center", marginRight: "5mm", pageBreakAfter: "always" }} >
                    <small className='fw-bold'>Sai Mart</small> <br />
                    <svg id={`barcode-${data.no}`} />
                    <p style={{ fontSize: "10px", fontWeight: "bold", marginTop: "2px" }}>{data.name}</p>
                    <p style={{ marginTop: "-5px", display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-around" }}>
                      <span style={{ fontSize: "10px", marginTop: "-1px", fontWeight: "bold", }}>Sale &#8377;. <span style={{ fontSize: "14px", }}>{data.salePrice}</span></span>
                      <span style={{ fontSize: "7px", fontWeight: "bold" }}>Exp :  {data.expDate}</span>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  {products[index + 1] && (
                    <div style={{ flex: 1, width: "38mm", marginTop: index === 0 ? "0px" : "10px", height: "25mm", border: "2px solid red", textAlign: "center", marginLeft: "5mm" }} >
                      <small className='fw-bold'>Sai Mart</small>
                      <svg id={`barcode-${products[index + 1].no}`} />
                      <p style={{ fontSize: "10px", fontWeight: "bold", marginTop: "2px" }}>{products[index + 1].name}</p>
                      <p style={{ marginTop: "-5px", display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-around" }}>
                        <span style={{ fontSize: "10px", marginTop: "-1px", fontWeight: "bold", }}>Sale &#8377;. <span style={{ fontSize: "14px", }}>{products[index + 1].salePrice}</span></span>
                        <span style={{ fontSize: "7px", fontWeight: "bold" }}>Exp :  {products[index + 1].expDate}</span>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  )}
                </div>
              )
            ))}
          </div>

        </Container >
      </div >

    </React.Fragment >
  );
};

export default PrintBarcodeCreate;
```

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page

Answer (score -1):

Find the updated code :

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="page-content" id="hide_scroll">
        <Button color="primary" onClick={handlePrint}>
          Print Barcodes
        </Button>
        <Container>
          <div id="printable-area" style={{ display: "grid" }}>
            {products.map(
              (data, index) =>
                index % 2 === 0 && (
                  <div
                    key={index + 1}
                    style={{
                      display: "flex",
                      width: "80mm",
                      height: "60mm",
                      margin: "0",
                    }}
                  >
                    <div
                      style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        width: "38mm",
                        height: "28mm",
                        marginTop: index === 0 ? "0px" : "10px",
                        border: "2px solid red",
                        textAlign: "center",
                        marginRight: "5mm",
                        pageBreakAfter: "always",
                      }}
                    >
                      <small className="fw-bold">Sai Mart</small> <br />
                      <svg id={`barcode-${data.no}`} />
                      <p
                        style={{
                          fontSize: "10px",
                          fontWeight: "bold",
                          marginTop: "2px",
                        }}
                      >
                        {data.name}
                      </p>
                      <p
                        style={{
                          marginTop: "-5px",
                          display: "flex",
                          justifyContent: "space-around",
                        }}
                      >
                        <span
                          style={{
                            fontSize: "10px",
                            marginTop: "-1px",
                            fontWeight: "bold",
                          }}
                        >
                          Sale &#8377;.{" "}
                          <span style={{ fontSize: "14px" }}>
                            {data.salePrice}
                          </span>
                        </span>
                        <span style={{ fontSize: "7px", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                          Exp : {data.expDate}
                        </span>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                    {products[index + 1] && (
                      <div
                        style={{
                          flex: 1,
                          width: "38mm",
                          marginTop: index === 0 ? "0px" : "10px",
                          height: "28mm",
                          border: "2px solid red",
                          textAlign: "center",
                          marginLeft: "5mm",
                        }}
                      >
                        <small className="fw-bold">Sai Mart</small>
                        <svg id={`barcode-${products[index + 1].no}`} />
                        <p
                          style={{
                            fontSize: "10px",
                            fontWeight: "bold",
                            marginTop: "2px",
                          }}
                        >
                          {products[index + 1].name}
                        </p>
                        <p
                          style={{
                            marginTop: "-5px",
                            display: "flex",
                            justifyContent: "space-around",
                          }}
                        >
                          <span
                            style={{
                              fontSize: "10px",
                              marginTop: "-1px",
                              fontWeight: "bold",
                            }}
                          >
                            Sale &#8377;.{" "}
                            <span style={{ fontSize: "14px" }}>
                              {products[index + 1].salePrice}
                            </span>
                          </span>
                          <span style={{ fontSize: "7px", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                            Exp : {products[index + 1].expDate}
                          </span>
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </div>
                )
            )}
          </div>
        </Container>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
```

Here is the output for this:

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: you are right sir. but i want to print the barcode labels. You might have heart that we have to print labels on the barcode to scan. so we have created a new page 25mm and 38mm height and width and then we get this problem i we send barcodes to print.

Comment: As per your comment, I can see that your design is also not correct, in the printer, it is not picking provided width and height, because it is picking the full width. I've edited the answer with the updated result. Please check if that helps. This will print your data into exact mm size. Also size of bar design needs to be updated/ some font etc needs to be reduced to fit into the 25mm height. for now I've updated it with 28mm height.